# C# WPF: Разворачивание диалоговых окон поверх главного при открытии

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня в программе имеется доп. окно. Его я открываю как диалоговое:

```
DialogWindow dialog = new DialogWindow();
dialog.ShowDialog();
```

Все отлично, как и задумано - пользователь не может взаимодействовать с главным окном пока открыто диалоговое, но есть одно НО:

Если свернуть оба окна, то при необходимости развернуть их обратно, при наведении на иконку программы на панели задач пользователь увидит 2 окна на выбор - главное и диалоговое.

Он может по каким-то причинам нажать на главное и оно откроется, но он не сможет с ним взаимодействовать. Придется снова наводиться на иконку приложения на панели задач и выбирать диалоговое, чтобы оно развернулось.

---

Здесь у меня 2 решения в голове:

1. Скрывать главное окно с панели задач, вызывая у него свойство `ShowInTaskbar = false;`. Это по сути то, что мне нужно, но в этом случае [**`окно исчезает на пару миллисекунд`**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1330771/c-wpf-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB), что выглядит не очень красиво при открытии диалога.
2. Как-то **заставить диалоговое окно автоматически разворачиваться** при открытии главного. Но можно ли это сделать - я не знаю.

**Подскажите, есть ли еще какие-то способы?**

Comment: Может быть получится записать диалогое окно в статическое поле главного? При при событии разворачивания главного проверяйте есть ли активное диалоговое и выводите его на передний план. Разумеется руками нужно будет добавлять/убирать из статического поля диалоговые окна.

Comment: Диалоговому задайте явно `ThowInTaskBar = false`.

Comment: Есть еще вариант - сделать вообще без диалогового окна. Ведь вы можете отображать все что угодно поверх чего угодно прямо в одном окне. Сделайте Grid во все окно (положите рядом с главным гридом окна), с полупрозрачным фоном, нарисуйте ему посередине белый прямоугольник Border, в нем пишите все то же самое что и в диалоговом окне. Далее привяжите Visibility этого грида. И готово.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ написан на основе совета `Blackmeser`, спасибо.

В классе главного окна добавил объект диалогового:

```
private Window currentDialog = null;
```

При открытии диалогового окна, `currentDialog` принимает значение открытого окна:

```
DialogWindow dialog = new DialogWindow();
currentDialog = dialog;
dialog.ShowDialog();
currentDialog = null;
```

При закрытии - снова `null`.

Добавил триггер, срабатывающий при получении фокуса главным окном:

```
Activated += OnFocus;
```

И сам метод `OnFocus`:

```
private void OnFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (currentDialog != null)
    {
        try
        {
            currentDialog.Activate();
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

**Готово! Теперь при разворачивании главного окна, если есть диалоговое, то оно открывается поверх главного**